# Business Objects 4 web Intelligence: How to create a button to switch tabs?

Tags: hyperlink, business-intelligence, business-objects

I have a multi-tab document. On my front page I would like to create a hyperlink to another tab.

This is what I've tried so far:

- Create a free standing cell with the text 'Press this!'
- Right click > Linking > Add Document link & point to the tab with these settings:

[image]

This has the problem of opening a new document and refreshing it (takes 3 to 5 minutes). **How can I make the 'Press this!' button just switch to the target tab without opening a new document or refreshing?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to jump to a different report within the same document. The OpenDocument feature you're using does just what its name implies: opening a document (optionally specifying which report within that document to show).

In summary: this feature is not supported.